# Flow3 PersonName Rollback

Tags: php, typo3-flow

I have a problem in the Security Account/Party Module of Flow3.

I've tried to change the first and last name of a Person as Party:

```
$person = $account->getParty();
$name = $person->getName();
$name->setFirstName($firstName);
$name->setLastName($lastName);
$this->accountRepository->update($account);
$this->partyRepository->update($person);
```

$account is a valid `\TYPO3\FLOW3\Security\Account` Object.

When using this Code and changing $firstName and $lastname, flow3 is doing a rollback.

I found a workaround:

```
$personName = new \TYPO3\Party\Domain\Model\PersonName('', $firstName,'', $lastName);
$person->setName($personName);
```

This works correctly, but why ??

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Person::getName()` returns a copy of `PersonName` and not a reference. That means that PersonName is not updated inside (`$this->name`) of `$person` if you change it on the outside (`$name`).

This would be one solution:

```
$person = $account->getParty();
$name = $person->getName();
$name->setFirstName($firstName);
$name->setLastName($lastName);
$person->setName($name);
$this->accountRepository->update($account);
$this->partyRepository->update($person);
```

Just set PersonName again.

This anwser is nice too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/746322/782920

PHP: returning by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php