# Array reference confusion in PHP

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(1);
$a = & $arr[0];

$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++;

echo $arr[0],$arr2[0];

// Output 2,2
```

Can you please help me how is it possible?

Comment: You want us to explain how it works?

Comment: he only increment on arr2 and wants to know why arr also is increment

Comment: He means that this behavior is peculiar as he sets $a as reference to $arr but never uses $a. This indeed is strange.

Comment: Not clear if it's what's happening or what he wants

Comment: @Robinv.G. The output written in comment is not correct. It can't be. Maybe there's a bug in that version of php that he uses.

Comment: @PLB running v5.4.4 and getting the same output.

Comment: I reproduced this behaviour, and it only occurs if the line `$a = & $arr[0];` is present.

Comment: @Yoshi OS? I am running the same version on xampp. Everything is as it should be.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks. I'll check what's wrong to my server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially
>   dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a
>   reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a
>   reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal
>   assignments. This also applies to function calls where the array is
>   passed by value.

```
/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
```

Comment: @DaveRandom Please abbreviate RTFM FTW. I'm afraid that i'm taking it the wrong way ;)

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas Yes, so which part is confusion from the manual?

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka RTFM FTW - Read The Full Manual  For The Win

Comment: @xdazz Confusion in assignment.$arr2 = $arr It is not a reference.Then why $arr[0] value is increased.

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas Because if the array contains references, then  references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(1);//creates an Array ( [0] => 1 ) and assigns it to $arr
$a = & $arr[0];//assigns by reference $arr[0] to $a and thus $a is a reference of $arr[0]. 
//Here $arr[0] is also replaced with the reference to the actual value i.e. 1

$arr2 = $arr;//assigns $arr to $arr2

$arr2[0]++;//increments the referenced value by one

echo $arr[0],$arr2[0];//As both $aar[0] and $arr2[0] are referencing the same block of memory so both echo 2

// Output 22
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like $arr[0] and $arr2[0] are pointing to the same allocated memory, so if you increment on one of the pointers , the int will be increment in the memory

Link [Are there pointers in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746224/are-there-pointers-in-php)

Comment: The question is _why_ it points to the same allocated memory.

Comment: i have not read it but, $arr2 = $arr; seems not to copy $arr but only to create a new pointer like in C