# How to use a pointer in a PHP function?

Tags: php, pointers

In C we can use pointer for a function parameter:

```
test( *text);
function test( *txt){
 //codes goes here
}
```

**Is it possible in PHP?**

Comment: Although there at no 'pointers' in PHP, you can pass 'references': [You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable.](https://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). e.g _`function test(&$param1);`_ would allow `$param1` to be modified in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names in PHP start with `$` so `$entryId` is the name of a variable.
`$this` is a special variable in Object Oriented programming in PHP, which is reference to current object.

`->` is used to access an object member (like properties or methods) in PHP, like the syntax in C++.

So your code means this: place the value of variable `$entryId` into the `entryId` field (or property) of this object.

The `&` operator in PHP, means pass reference. Here is an example:

```
$b=2;
$a=$b;
$a=3;
print $a;
print $b;
// output is 32

$b=2;
$a=&$b; // note the & operator
$a=3;
print $a;
print $b;
// output is 33
```

In the above code, because we used `&` operator, a reference to where `$b` is pointing is stored in `$a`. So `$a` is actually a reference to `$b`.

There is a good explanation of pointers on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746224/are-there-pointers-in-php)

Comment: i have updated my answer ^^ .

Answer (score 1):

There are references, but that's **not** the same as pointers.

php.net has multiple pages explaining [What References Are](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php), [What References Do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) and [What References Are Not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php).
There too, it is mentioned multiple times that

> References are not pointers.

They provide a way to assign `$a` to `$b`  so that if you reassign `$b`, `$a` changes as well:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = &$a; // Reference
$b = 'b'; // Now $a == 'b'
```

This can be used for function arguments as well:

```
function myFunc(&$b)
{
    $b = 'b';
}
$a = 'a';
myFunc($a); // Now $a == 'b'
```

Before PHP 5.3.0 is was also possible to do a thing called "call-time pass-by-reference", where you would have a "normal" function declaration and use the `&` operator in the call instead:

```
function myFunc($b)
{
    $b = 'b';
}
$a = 'a';
myFunc(&$a); // As of PHP 5.3.0 produces a Fatal Error, saying:
             // Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed; If you would like to pass argument by reference, modify the declaration of myFunc().
```

But beware! Assigning another **reference** will not update the original reference:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$c = &$a;
$c = &$b; // $a == 'a'
```

[ [Demo](http://3v4l.org/KUELm) ]

A trap resulting from that exists with the `global` keyword.

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';

function myFunc()
{
    global $a, $b;
    $a = &$b;
    var_dump($a);
}

myFunc();       // 'b'
var_dump($a);   // 'a'
```

That is because `global $a` effectively means `$a = &$GLOBALS['a']`, so assigning it a new reference will not update `$GLOBALS`.
Of course you can prevent that by using `$GLOBALS` directly.
But if you're using globals at all, you should probably rethink your design anyway.

With references, there is now also a difference between setting a variable `= NULL` and using `unset()`.
`= NULL` follows references, `unset()` does not:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = &$a;
unset($b); // $a == 'a'

$a = 'a';
$b = &$a;
$b = NULL; // $a == NULL
```

[ [Demo](http://3v4l.org/HXVIN) ]

---

Bottom line:

References allow for things that wouldn't be possible without them, but sometimes do not behave the way one would expect them to, because of how PHP was built.